# "At this time yesterday, I had gone" vs. "by this time yesterday, I had gone"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, past-perfect, at-by

> At this time yesterday, I was going to work. [Past Continuous]

I am very sure that the above sentence is 100% correct. (Reference: http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastcontinuous.html.)

But I doubt that the one below is grammatical:

> At this time yesterday, I had gone to work. [Past Perfect]

Note how I used *at*, not *by*. I see the following difference:

- At this time yesterday ⇒ Exactly on this time yesterday not after it neither prior to it.
- By this time yesterday ⇒ No longer than this time yesterday, it might be either exactly on this time yesterday or slightly *before* it.

It's known that the Past Perfect tense refers to completed actions *before* something in the past. That's why one of the time expressions of the Past Perfect is "by this time yesterday".

A friend of mine said, and I quote, "It's correct. if u say ' at this time yesterday I had gone to work' it means that u had already arrived to the work." (Sic.) But I couldn't agree less with him.

So my question is, is it grammatical in Standard English (I'm not talking about colloquial English nor dialects) to say:

> **At** this time yesterday, I had gone to work.

Or should I use *by*?

Comment: "By" is certainly correct, and is better to use there than "at". Whether "at" is also grammatically correct is a tricky question.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow me to tweak slightly:

*I had gone to work at 6 o'clock.*

*At 6 o'clock, I had gone to work.*

Both these are fine if there is a context allowing them, such as:

Yesterday, I returned home at 10 pm and was fast asleep within ten minutes. My day had been very busy - I had risen before dawn, and done my usual 3-mile jog before returning for a shower and breakfast. I had gone to work at 6 o'clock. ...

But the expression indicates the time at which "I" went to work (left home), not some time by which (as you say) I was at work or some way along my way to work. To avoid confusion, choose *by*.

Comment: But, the time expression which "At this time yesterday" being used in this instance does not comply, if you like, with "Past perfect". I would appreciate that you give me a straight forward answer, apart from the context and "By this time yesterday" is better. Consider the sentence as an answer to a question. 
Question: Bla bla bla? 
Answer: By this time yesterday, I had gone to work. 
In this case, according to GRAMAMR, is this sentence correct or incorrect? 
Thank you very much indeed, guys.

Comment: Chomsky famously showed that it is ridiculous to use **just** syntactic reasoning to decide whether a given string should be considered acceptable. The grammar in the examples I gave is acceptable. The meaning you require (I had already left by this time yesterday) needs _by_ rather than _at_, for the reasons you yourself give.

Comment: @BrightPolyglot Q:"At this time yesterday you were still at home, were you not?" A:"No, indeed; at this time yesterday I had gone to work" ***OR*** "No, indeed; by this time yesterday I had gone to work." Either will serve.